# Python Best Practices: Abstract Syntax Trees

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

### Modifying Abstract Syntax Trees

I would like to be able to build and modify an `ast` and then optionally write it out as python byte code for execution later without overhead.

I have been hacking around with the [ast docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/ast.html) for `python3.0` and `python2.6`, but I can't seem to find any good sources on best practices for this type of code.

### Question

What are some best practices and guidelines for modifying abstract syntax trees in python?

### [edit]

[Unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57757/unknown) states that [byteplay](http://code.google.com/p/byteplay/) is a good example of such a library.

Also, [benford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103377/benford) cites [GeniuSQL](http://www.aminus.net/geniusql) which uses abstract syntax trees to transform python code to SQL.

Comment: What kind of project is this for?  Sounds like it'll be really cool.

Comment: I'm working on a template generator/compiler for appengine that does up front code gen for performance.  Also, I'm working on some evolutionary algorithms in pyevolve which need to modify code structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other than the manual and the source code, you are on your own. This subject and python bytecode are very undocumented.

Alternatively you could try using this python bytecode library which I have heard good thing about but haven't tried it yet:

http://code.google.com/p/byteplay/

Comment: Thanks!  I was afraid this would be the answer.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2):

I think geniusql is doing something along those lines to translate an ast into sql... There was a talk on it but I can't find it - and I'm not allowed to link anyway :-(